# partially filling svg/png with color using css

Tags: css, html, png

I am new in CSS HTML. I am trying to following thing with CSS. I have a png icon. Now I want to partially fill-up it with color from bottom to top like the link of the image.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to animate or just fill? If animation, is it infinite? or triggered on `:hover`? Please add some more details. Also, you can't animate png colors if that is what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details. I am not trying to animate. It will be static actually. I have tried using css but failed. here is the css
http://codepen.io/samiul_anik/pen/ByZRdN
I tried to put the yellow marker at the bottom of the black marker. But could not do it.

Comment: This is pretty easy using `svg`. ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvxjomug/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got two good solutions to work with :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?
I inserted a div (represents the filling) into your pin and set the `position` property to `absolute`. Further I changed the `position` property of the parent `div` which represents the pin to `relative`, now you can align your filling absolute but within its parent.

```css
body,
html {
  height :100%;
}
body {
  background: #2F2F2F;
}
.pin {
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin-fill {
  width :10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  transform: rotate(1 deg);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='pin'>
  <div class="pin-fill"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you want your inner pin (`.pin-fill`) look like a filling, I would suggest to change your it's `border-radius` as following.

`border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;`

**Snippet**

```css
body,
html {
  height :100%;
}
body {
  background: #2F2F2F;
}
.pin {
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin-fill {
  width :10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(1 deg);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='pin'>
  <div class="pin-fill"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is an example with plain filling**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #2F2F2F;
}
.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin-fill {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='pin'>
  <div class="pin-fill"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can this answer has just 1 point, very well explained and great example!